# Survey Monkey API V3 - Survey title when creating from an existing survey

Tags: c#, surveymonkey

I'm upgrading a C# application used at work to gather client satisfaction stats using Survey Monkey. The upgrade is to make it use the Survey Monkey API V3 instead of V2 (since V2 gets turned off soon). Both versions of our code make use of Ben Emmett's excellent .NET wrapper(https://github.com/bcemmett/SurveyMonkeyApi) extended with appropriate methods to support creating new surveys and sending invitations.

In version 2 we used the Create_Flow API method to generate new surveys based on an existing one (we have a couple of existing base surveys and choose the appropriate one based on the type of project we're surveying about). It's important that the title of the new survey reflect the name of the relevant project. The relevant part of our V2 code looks like this:

```
        var data = new CreateFlowSettings();
        data.survey.survey_title = legislationTitle;
        data.survey.from_survey_id = fromSurveyId;
        data.collector.recipients = recipients;
        data.email_message.subject = subject;
        data.email_message.body_text = bodyText;
        data.email_message.reply_email = replyEmail;

        var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        const string endPoint = "/batch/create_flow";
        var response = MakeApiRequest(endPoint, serializedData);
        var createFlowResponse =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateFlowResponseObjects.CreateFlowResponse>(response.ToString());
        return createFlowResponse;
```

In V3 we create our surveys using the /surveys endpoint like so (the term 'template' used in the code below is not a reference to the Survey Monkey concept of template surveys):

```
        public Survey CreateSurvey(string templateSurveyid, string newSurveyTitle)
    {
        const string endpoint = "/surveys";
        var requestData = new RequestData {{"from_survey_id", templateSurveyid}, {"title", newSurveyTitle}};
        var result = MakeApiRequest(endpoint, Verb.POST, requestData);
        return result.ToObject<Survey>();
    }
```

In V2 the title of the survey displayed at the top of each page in our new surveys would reflect the 'survey_title' data we sent with the API request. In V3 however the 'title' value is NOT replacing the text appearing at the top of each page. It IS correctly determining the name of the survey on the site but at the top of each page we see the title of the survey on which the new one was based (the survey with the id passed to the API as 'from_survey_id').

I think I've googled this pretty extensively and can't find anybody else describing this problem. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Do I need to code modifying the survey after creation to achieve this in V3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this is a bug in API v3. Only part of the survey title is being updated on copy survey.

This has been resolved - expect a fix out (likely sometime this week) and it will start working without any changes on your side.

Note: PATCH on the survey should be working properly (but I wouldn't recommend coding around the issue unless necessary)